# Weighted Cohen's Kappa with 'irr' package

Tags: r

In the `irr` package, the sample code is:

`kappa2(ratings, weight = c("unweighted", "equal", "squared"), sort.levels = FALSE)`

Would the `"equal"` weighted option be equivalent to a linear weighted kappa? I'm having trouble figuring out which option would be linear versus quadratic.